# How to retrieve history version of Wikipedia article by given date?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Is there a way to use MediaWiki API or any other tool to automatically retrieve a previous version of a Wikipedia article using an approximate date (without knowing the 'oldid' value)?

For example how can I retrieve the [history version of Stack Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stack_Overflow&oldid=755799157) article from 20 December 2016 by using *"December 2016"*, *"20 December 2016"* or a date around this day as parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Brevisions) with action **query** and property **revisions**. To get the first revision of the [Stack Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) made after 00:00:00 on 20 December 2016 you can use this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Stack%20Overflow&rvlimit=1&rvprop=content&rvdir=newer&rvstart=2016-12-20T00:00:00Z
```

where **rvlimit** is the number of history versions to be returned, **rvdir=newer** means the results (if rvlimit > 1) to be listed in order from oldest to newest, and **rvstart** is the time after which the page history versions are taken.

Answer (score 0):

A curl request on the [Special:Export](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_Special:Export) page might also help, by setting the offset parameter to something like '2016-12-20T00:00:00Z'

```
curl -d "" 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&pages=Stack_Overflow&offset=2016-12-20T00:00:00Z&limit=1&action=submit'
```