# Browsing old version of wikipedia using Wikipedia API

Tags: version, wikipedia-api

I would like parse wikipedia Data, but through time snapshots of the site, using the wikipedia API.

However, if it seems that it's possible to browse through different version of an article, I cannot find a way to browse article given a specific date or timespan.
Is their a way to do something like this using this API ?

for instance, if I use this code in python. I get the current 500 first categories.

```
    import requests as rq

    S = rq.Session()
    url="https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
    
    PARAMS = {
    "action": "query",
    "format": "json",
    "list": "allcategories",
    "acmin":100,
    "aclimit": 500
    }

    R = S.get(url=url, params=PARAMS)
    DATA = R.json()
```

However, if I wanted to have access to the first 500 categories that were existing in wikipedia in january 2015, how would I do ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718800/how-to-retrieve-history-version-of-wikipedia-article-by-given-date?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve history version of Wikipedia article by given date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718800/how-to-retrieve-history-version-of-wikipedia-article-by-given-date)